# Is it possible to run wndows 8.1 on vmware player on a Ubuntu Pc?

Tags: windows-8, virtualization

The only reason I have windows is because I do Directx programming and I'm stuck with visual studio but I really prefer Ubuntu a lot better. Is there anyway to run visual studio inside a windows 8.1 vm using vmware player?

Answer (score 0):

Just install Windows 8.1 inside vmware like any other virtual machine.  Then use your software inside of that virtual machine just as you would with a native 8.1 platform.